# how can i enter the number in Dial Pad without bot telling next options to the customer?

Tags: skypedeveloper, botframework

I am working on bot framework technology, by using Skype Calling feature I have tried with different scenario as “once bot asking to the customer like press 1 to enter account number” then I am trying to enter the account number from Dial Pad but whenever I pressed one digit In Dial Pad then immediately bot telling other options to the customer like “press 2 to enter the pin” or “Press 3 to repeat these options again”.

I have followed the below link to implement above scenario.
https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/calling.html

And also I want account number and pin what I enter in Dial Pad.

Please tell me how to resolve the above issue.

-Pradeep

Comment: There isn't sufficient information in your scenario to understand your question.  Please add some code or more detail.  Thanks.

Comment: when I am calling to bot using skype calling feature at that time my bot tell some options like press 1 to enter your account number at that time I am trying to enter my account using dial pad then bot immediately tell other options when I pressed one digit it will not wait until I entered my account number 11 digits.